# How to use the Max extension method?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm really confused on how to use extension methods...
I'm trying to use the extended max method from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

My (simplified) code:

```
namespace grades
{
    public class Grades
    {
        private List<int> grades;

        public int max()
        {
            return grades.Max(); // Not finding the extended Max function...
        }
    }
}
```

Am I using this wrong? If someone could write out code for how to properly use these extended methods?

Comment: What's not working? What are you expecting? What's actually happening? Also, your grades variable is not scoped in your max() method.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry, copy+paste error.

Comment: What is the *exact* error you're seeing?  Have you included the namespace which has the extension method in question?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a using statement, but I can't be sure since those weren't included in your post.

Answer (score 6):

Add `using System.Linq;` namespace

Comment: Oh, wow. Thanks... Do I need System.Linq for all extension methods defined in msdn?

Comment: @Shaku all defined in Linq, not msdn

Comment: @Shaku you should read a bit about assemblies, references, and using directives.

Comment: Each method has defined namespace where is placed if you display detail of extension method

Answer (score 4):

[`Enumerable.Max`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) is available in `System.Linq` namesapce. You have to add that.

```
using System.Linq;
```

See: [Extension Methods - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)

> The most common extension methods are the LINQ standard query
>   operators that add query functionality to the existing
>   System.Collections.IEnumerable and
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable types. **To use the standard
>   query operators, first bring them into scope with a using System.Linq
>   directive.** Then any type that implements IEnumerable appears to
>   have instance methods such as GroupBy, OrderBy, Average, and so on.
>   You can see these additional methods in IntelliSense statement
>   completion when you type "dot" after an instance of an IEnumerable
>   type such as List or Array.